# Display Posts By DYNAMIC Tag

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Although I have experience with PHP, WordPress is pretty new to me and I am struggling here.

I am trying to help a friend complete a theme. He works with several artists and each artist has a WP page named after the artist (i.e., Tom Jones) on which he wants to display only the posts about that artist. We define a tag for each artist ( Tom Jones ) with a slug like ( tom-jones )

Following the Codex, I am prepping the Loop in the template as follows:

```
$tags = get_tags();
//query_posts( array( 'tag' => $tag->slug ) );
query_posts( array( 'tag' => 'tom-jones' ) );

if( have_posts()) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  echo '<li id="feed<?php theID(); ?>" style="border-bottom:1px solid #404040;">';
  echo '<table><tr><td width="40">';
  echo '<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image_path', true); ?>" />';
  echo '</td><td><a href="';
  the_permalink(); 
  echo '">';
  the_title();                            
  echo '</a><br><span class="smTxt">Posted by ';
  the_author();
  echo ' on <em>';
  the_time('F jS, Y');
  echo '</em></span><br>';
  the_excerpt();
  echo '</td></tr></table></li>';
  endwhile;
else:
  echo '<h3>There are no posts.</h3>';
endif;
```

I would have thought that the query_post that is commented out would have grabbed the particular slug of the artist but it returns "No Posts". When I hard code as it is now, it works as expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain in which file you are using this code ?

Comment: page-artist.php (a template page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
query_posts( array( 'tag' => get_query_var('tag') ) );
```

[This post may help you](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/need-to-get-the-slug-value-for-use-in-another-data-table).

**Update:**

As you said `artist` is a custom `texonomy` so try this

```
$the_tax = get_taxonomy( get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
query_posts( array( 'artist' => $the_tax->labels->name ) );
```

Must use `wp_reset_query()` after the loop when you are using `query_posts`

[You may read this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-current-taxonomy-name-on-taxonomyphp).

**Update:** (using WP_Query)

```
$the_tax = get_taxonomy( get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'artist',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $the_tax->labels->name
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: that returns all of the posts ... no limiting

Comment: all of the posts on the site were listed with that query rather than a group of posts limited by the specific artist tag

Comment: I'm really confused, can you tell me what `get_query_var('tag')` and `$term[0]->slug` returns if you echo it ?

Comment: get_query_var('tag') returns nothing when echoed

Comment: What is `artist` ? A category ?

Comment: this is what I have now before the if clause

Comment: $tags = get_tags();
var_dump($tags);
//query_posts( array( 'tag' => $slug ) );
query_posts( array( 'tag' => 'tom-jones' ) );

Comment: here's the varm dump of $tags

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#117 (9) { ["term_id"]=> string(1) "7" ["name"]=> string(12) "Tom Jones" ["slug"]=> string(12) "tom-jones" ["term_group"]=> string(1) "0" ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> string(2) "41" ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> string(1) "0" ["count"]=> string(1) "3" }

Comment: [1]=> object(stdClass)#118 (9) { ["term_id"]=> string(2) "32" ["name"]=> string(11) "Misty Blythe" ["slug"]=> string(11) "misty-blythe" ["term_group"]=> string(1) "0" ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> string(2) "43" ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> string(1) "0" ["count"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: keeping in line with the example I have been using, the URL would be www.wynnewade.com/ppm-music/tom-jones

Comment: Please read [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: I read it a long ago and I didn't try to make it more complicated here but only mistake I've made that I didn't use `wp_resewt_query` here and I think the answer is accepted and it was not necessary to down vote, instead you could have just remind me about the fact by only leaving a message.

Comment: Thanks a lot you appreciated it :-)